# Use of singlequotes when writing HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code inside a php file:

```
<script>

var myString = '{$data10}'; 
if (myString.charAt(0)) {
    document.write('<a target="_blank" 
                       href="https://www.somedomain.com/join?id={$data10}">
                    <img src="images/join-bim.png" width="300" height="74" 
                         onMouseOut="this.src="images/join-bim.png"" 
                         onMouseOver="this.src="images/join-bimB.png"" /></a>');
} else {
    document.write('<a target="_blank" 
                       href="https://www.somedomain.com/join?id=111111">
                    <img src="images/join-bim.png" width="300" height="74" 
                         onMouseOut="this.src="images/join-bim.png"" 
                         onMouseOver="this.src="images/join-bimB.png"" /></a>');
}
</script>
```

I have tried:

```
onMouseOut="this.src="images/join-bim.png""
```

but encountered problems due to the quotes not nesting.

Because of that, I then tried:

```
onMouseOut="this.src='images/join-bim.png'"
```

However, the single quotes are not being accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use escaped single quotes, as you can see below

```
<script>
var myString = '{$data10}'; 
    if(myString.charAt(0)){
        document.write('<a target="_blank" href="https://www.somedomain.com/join?id={$data10}"><img src="images/join-bim.png" width="300" height="74" onMouseOut="this.src=\'images/join-bim.png\'" onMouseOver="this.src=\'images/join-bimB.png\'" /></a>');
    }
    else {
        document.write('<a target="_blank" href="https://www.somedomain.com/join?id=111111"><img src="images/join-bim.png" width="300" height="74" onMouseOut="this.src=\'images/join-bim.png\'" onMouseOver="this.src=\'images/join-bimB.png\'" /></a>'); 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you must escape inner quotes

```
onMouseOver="this.src=\"images/join-bimB.png\""
```

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are not escaped, meaning your quotes inside is closing the first quote, making PHP confused.

To escape it, use for your inner-single quotes:

```
onMouseOver=\'this.src="images/join-bimB.png"\'
```